# Getting CloudBlobDirectory size without doing a listBlob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to see if there is a more efficient way to get the size of CloudBlobDirectory (including the CloudBlobs within it).  I am seeing listBlobs() along with "blob.downloadAttributes()" for each blob take 10-15 minutes for ~10,000 blobs.  This is what I am doing currently:

```
        for (ListBlobItem blobItem : azAccount.getContainer().listBlobs(path)) {
            if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
                CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
                blob.downloadAttributes();
                totalSize += blob.getProperties().getLength();
            }
        }
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do the additional downloadAttributes. If you simply delete that line, I think you'll see it works. ListBlobs populates the content length property for the blobs it returns.

Comment: Yes, Emily is right. And I don't think there is a more efficient way to get the size of CloudBlobDirectory/CloudBlobContainer. (Please note that CloudBlobDirectory is a virtual concept which doesn't really exist.)